# Python barcode scanner

Tags: python, barcode-scanner

I have already read around the site about how to just get the input from a barcode scanner but I am not sure on how I should actually do it.

I will be using this barcode scanner: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Esky-Wireless-Handheld-Barcode-Rechargeable/dp/B00O9P3Z7C/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1482066778&sr=8-6&keywords=usb+barcode+scanner

I basically need to when a user clicks return button in my tkinter window I need the program to be a while loop until a input is received from the scanner, then I will be using that to scanner to see if it is in my database.

I can do the SQL and everything else, but I am not actually sure what the best way is to strip the data from the barcode scanner since it should act as a keyboard.

Edit: I have attempted this:

```
 barcode = simpledialog.askstring("Barcode scan", "Please scan the barcode of the laptop you rented")

cursor.execute("SELECT barcode FROM laptops WHERE idlaptops=%s",laptopid)
barcodefetch = fetchResult(cursor)
actualbarcode = barcodefetch[0]["barcode"]

if barcode != actualbarcode:
    messagebox.showinfo("Barcode invalid", "Barcode did not match please scan the barcode again")
    return
```

Would the scanner type into the askstring box?

Comment: `Would the scanner type into the askstring box?`  try it.

Comment: I haven't got the scanner for a while but I am programming before hand for when it arrives as I have a deadline to meet. I will put that in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A barcode scanner is viewed by the computer as a keyboard.
As long as a text field in a window has the focus, when the trigger is pulled, the code is typed in the field, the same way you would do with a keyboard.

Comment: Okay thank you. Lots of people have asked this before and everybody seems to give like sample code etc why is it needed?

Comment: this seems to be a pretty universal convention huh, I was wondering what the deal was when watching this video of a barcode doing entry into excel. The neat thing was they had these meta-barcodes that would change the configuration of the scanner somehow. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgXgXbmDh8A.